# Change Label Text with Controls in VB

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change a Label Text with Controls command, using this line

```
Controls("C_" & 0).Text = "Conta:"
```

But I get this error

"System.NullReferenceException"

If I delete this label and change it for a textbox (with same name "C_0"), it works! But I need to do this with a Label not a textbox...

[image: Textlabel named "C_0"]

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce. I have created Label `L_0`, TextBox `T_0`, and CheckBox `C_0`, and used this code:         `Controls("L_" & 0).Text = "Conta:"` 
        `Controls("T_" & 0).Text = "Conta:"` 
        `Controls("C_" & 0).Text = "Conta:"`, and all the controls' Text properties have been set. You must either not have that control, or you have a typo. Also, don't use string concatenation `&` on an integer. Use a Formatter or string interpolation.

Comment: You can also show all your Labels' names in a MessageBox: `MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", Controls.OfType(Of Label).Select(Function(l) l.Name)))` to confirm you actually have it.

Comment: Take a look in photos which I added...

Hmm, I'll take a look in string interpolation! Thanks

MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", Controls.OfType(Of Label).Select(Function(l) l.Name)))
Shows a blank messagebox for me!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you do not have a control named `C_0`. I would suggest using [ControlCollection.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?view=netframework-4.8) to get your control and then use a conditional If statement to check if the returned control exists:

```
Dim desiredControls() As Control = Me.Controls.Find("C_" & 0, True)
If desiredControls.Count = 0 Then
    'No controls named C_0 found
ElseIf desiredControls.Count > 1 Then
    'Multiple controls named C_0 found
Else
    desiredControls(0).Text = "Conta:"
End If
```

Or if you simply wanted a one-liner then you would use:

```
Me.Controls.Find("C_" & 0, True).First().Text = "Conta:"
```

However, I would highly recommend that you use the conditional If statements so that you an exception isn't thrown if 0 controls are found.

Comment: Ok guys, I think I find the problem... I made a new label named C_0 and It worked!!! The old label didn't... I don't know why... Maybe it's corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I find the problem... This command wasn't working because it was inside a GroupBox.

Then the right code is

```
Me.Controls("GroupBox1").Controls("C_" & 0).Text = "123"
```

Thanks for everyone help!

Comment: If you would use the code that I provided, this would not be an issue because of the ControlCollection.Find method's `searchAllChildren` parameter.

Comment: That's true, I'm trying to make this as short as posible. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you really want a one-liner solution, check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is control.Controls only returns the controls directly inside the control. So you can use these extension methods. Put this in a Module:

```
<Extension>
Public Function ChildControls(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Return ChildControls(Of Control)(parent)
End Function

<Extension>
Public Function ChildControls(Of TControl As Control)(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of TControl)
    Dim result As New List(Of TControl)
    For Each ctrl As Control In parent.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is TControl Then result.Add(CType(ctrl, TControl))
        result.AddRange(ctrl.ChildControls(Of TControl)())
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Here is how you would use it:

```
' general option to return all controls, filter on name
Me.ChildControls().Single(Function(c) c.Name = "C_" & 0)).Text = "Conta:"

' generic option to return only Labels, filter on name
Me.ChildControls(Of Label)().Single(Function(c) c.Name = "C_" & 0)).Text = "Conta:"
```

This will work whether the Label is in the GroupBox or not, and if you move it to a different GroupBox, Panel, or back to the Form, without needing to change your code.