# Checkbox "Checked" function with VB Controls

Tags: vb.net

I've multiples CheckBoxes named "CB_0", "CB_1", "CB_2" and so far... I'm trying to change their "Checked" state, but "Controls" doesn't recognize the "Checked" property.

My line of code is like this:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Controls($"CB_{i}").Checked = True
```

It doesn't works, but if I use this:

```
CB_0.Checked = True
```

It works, how can I fix that?

Note:

If I try to change it text, it works:

```
Dim i As Integer = 0
Controls($"CB_{i}").Text = "Hello"
```

Comment: You need to cast it.  Ctype(Controls($"CB_{i}"), Checkbox).Checked

Comment: You could use an array and add the name of the controls to the array and then manipulate them from there.

Comment: If you used [the extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56793938/832052) I gave you in your other question, you would just use the overload with the generic `Me.ChildControls(Of CheckBox)().Single(Function(c) c.Name = $"CB_{i}")).Text = "Hello"`

Comment: Yes! But I'm new in VB and in programming, I tried to understand this line of code but I couldn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your looking for?

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    CType(Controls($"CB_{i}"), CheckBox).Checked = True
```

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or `DirectCast`